# Onclick return value with label

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi what I'm trying to achieve with this line of code is to return a value to be used by a SQL statement in the same page, currently doing something wrong i guess you can't insert **value** to a label element. Would appreciate any suggestions on doing this.

```
     <td align="center">
                        <label value='yearlvl' 'onclick="this.form.submit();">
                        <?php echo $row[0];?></label>
      </td>
```

Comment: please share entire HTML that also contains the form

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Maybe provide more code. Do you want it so when you click the label, it runs a query and displays the result where the echo is?

Comment: @sachleen Yes that is particularly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @sachleen I can't find a good way too pass the value to my SQL query. Anyway that an element can hold two values?

Comment: You're gonna have to show us the rest of your code then...

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quote before `onclick`. That might be causing your problem..

It should be:

```
<td align="center">
    <label value='yearlvl' onclick="this.form.submit();">
        <?php echo $row[0];?>
    </label>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't seem to get the onclick to function and return values.